# Is there a way to distribute values in one column of null values in other column in SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I have

| region | district | subs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | 500 |
| Akmola | Kokshetau | 150 |
| Almaty | Taldykorgan | 500 |
| Aktobe | Aktobe | 400 |

What I want to get

| region | district | subs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Akmola | Kokshetau | 316 |
| Almaty | Taldykorgan | 666 |
| Aktobe | Aktobe | 566 |

Is there a way to equally distribute value in column (subs / revenue) that is NULL in other column (district), among other values that are not null in the same column.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) [mcve]

Comment: What would you expect to hapen if the NULL value is not equally divisible by the number of values it is to be spread over? e.g. here you have 500, which is not exactly divisible by 3.

Comment: I will try to explain this way: if NULL value is equal for instance, to 508625 and number of records is equal 567, I expect that exact number from result of 508625 / 567 operation will be distributed among those 567 records.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
SELECT region
     , district
     , subs + sum(subs) FILTER (WHERE region IS NULL) OVER() / count(*) FILTER (WHERE region IS NOT NULL) OVER () :: integer AS subs
  FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but I guess you want something like:

```
select region
     , district
     , subs + (select subs/(select count(1) from t where region is not null) from t where region is null)
from t
where region is not null;

region  district    (No column name)
Akmola  Kokshetau   316
Almaty  Taldykorgan 666
Aktobe  Aktobe      566
```